# How can I prevent DoFile() calls in an threaded environment with gopher-lua?

Tags: go, lua

these are my first steps with gopher-lua. So far I have a worker thread that receives "Actions" over a channel. The worker shall provide the action as a Lua module (so far I have no idea on how to do it better!). In a Lua script, I can import the module and use several getters to get all necessary nformation from this action.

Here is the action module:

```golang
package action

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/croessner/authserv/server/decl"
    "github.com/croessner/authserv/server/logging"
    "github.com/go-kit/log/level"
    "github.com/yuin/gopher-lua"
)

var Actions chan *Action

type Action struct {
    Repeating  bool
    ScriptPath string
    ClientIP   string
    ClientPort string
    ClientNet  string
    Username   string
    Password   string
    Protocol   string
}

func (a *Action) Loader(L *lua.LState) int {
    mod := L.SetFuncs(L.NewTable(), map[string]lua.LGFunction{
        "is_repeating":    a.isRepeating,
        "get_client_ip":   a.getClientIP,
        "get_client_port": a.getClientPort,
        "get_client_net":  a.getClientNet,
        "get_username":    a.getUsername,
        "get_password":    a.getPassword,
        "get_protocol":    a.getProtocol,
    })

    L.Push(mod)

    return 1
}

func (a *Action) isRepeating(L *lua.LState) int {
    L.Push(lua.LBool(a.Repeating))

    return 1
}

func (a *Action) getClientIP(L *lua.LState) int {
    L.Push(lua.LString(a.ClientIP))

    return 1
}

func (a *Action) getClientPort(L *lua.LState) int {
    L.Push(lua.LString(a.ClientPort))

    return 1
}

func (a *Action) getClientNet(L *lua.LState) int {
    L.Push(lua.LString(a.ClientNet))

    return 1
}

func (a *Action) getUsername(L *lua.LState) int {
    L.Push(lua.LString(a.Username))

    return 1
}

func (a *Action) getPassword(L *lua.LState) int {
    L.Push(lua.LString(a.Password))

    return 1
}

func (a *Action) getProtocol(L *lua.LState) int {
    L.Push(lua.LString(a.Protocol))

    return 1
}

func Worker(ctx context.Context) {
    var a *Action

    Actions = make(chan *Action)

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            break
        case a = <-Actions:
            func() {
                L := lua.NewState()

                defer L.Close()

                L.PreloadModule("as_action", a.Loader)

                // Other useful modules, i.e.: L.PreloadModule("as_http", gluahttp.NewHttpModule(&http.Client{}).Loader)

// THE PROBLEM STARTS HERE BY LOADING THE FILE EACH TIME!

                if err := L.DoFile(a.ScriptPath); err != nil {
                    level.Error(logging.DefaultErrLogger).Log(decl.LogKeyError, err)

                    return
                }
            }()
        }
    }
}
```

A Go process can do something like:

```golang
// Many calls!
go func() {
    action.Actions <- &action.Action{
        Repeating:  false,
        ScriptPath: "./server/lua-plugins.d/actions/bruteforce.lua",
        ClientIP:   "1.2.3.4",
        ClientPort: "12345",
        ClientNet:  "1.2.3.0/24",
        Username:   "alice",
        Password:   "secret",
        Protocol:   "http",
    }
}()
```

The bruteforce.lua looks something like this (example):

```lua
local action = require("as_action")

print("IP="       .. action.get_client_ip())
print("Port="     .. action.get_client_port())
print("Net="      .. action.get_client_net())
print("Username=" .. action.get_username())
print("Password=" .. action.get_password())
print("Protocol=" .. action.get_protocol())

if action.is_repeating() then
    print("Action is repeating")
end

-- Do something with the data...
```

As you can see, sending "Actions" will always re-create a new module and it will always open the lua file for each request. I feel that I am doing it the wrong way, even this is currently working.

Is there a better way to "deliver" data from the Action-struct to Lua and to *not* use DoFile() calls on any invokation? I guess the latter is more important than the first question, but it might depend on each other.

I also feel that it might be a problem to create lots of LStates! Maybe also related to the wrong approach I took.

Any help is very welcome and many thanks in advance.

Comment: From cursory glance, [this](https://github.com/yuin/gopher-lua#sharing-lua-byte-code-between-lstates) looks like what you're after, no?

Comment: I can not compile the file in front of the for{} loop, because the shown "Actions" struct contains the script path dynamically.

Comment: I still do not get it: from your question, I gather that you'd spawn multiple goroutines with each `Action` getting the same script. If so, what's the problem or compiling it once and then passing each action the compiled form?

Comment: The action-handling shall be dynamic, so the ScriptPath is a member in the Action-struct. Second problem is that all struct values are dynamic and if I only have _one_ LState, the PreLoadModule is done only once and all ongoing actions share the same wrong values. If you have a look at the lua example above: I have getters for each struct field. And of course that must provide current data; not the data which was initally preloaded (module with the first call. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's so far as I can see,

- It looks like there wont write `Action` by Lua. Why not a Lua table to "deliver" data instead.
- [Sharing Lua byte code between LStates](https://github.com/yuin/gopher-lua?tab=readme-ov-file#sharing-lua-byte-code-between-lstates) as @kostix mentioned.
- It is a way to avoid create lots of LStates if you need: [The LState pool pattern](https://github.com/yuin/gopher-lua?tab=readme-ov-file#the-lstate-pool-pattern)

I tend to set the action module up like this:

```golang
package action

import (
    "bufio"
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"

    lua "github.com/yuin/gopher-lua"
    "github.com/yuin/gopher-lua/parse"
)

var Actions chan *Action

type Action struct {
    Repeating  bool
    ScriptPath string
    ClientIP   string
    ClientPort string
    ClientNet  string
    Username   string
    Password   string
    Protocol   string
}

func (a *Action) ToLuaTable() *lua.LTable {
    tab := &lua.LTable{}
    tab.RawSet(lua.LString("Repeating"), lua.LBool(a.Repeating))
    tab.RawSet(lua.LString("ClientIP"), lua.LString(a.ClientIP))
    tab.RawSet(lua.LString("ClientPort"), lua.LString(a.ClientPort))
    tab.RawSet(lua.LString("ClientNet"), lua.LString(a.ClientNet))
    tab.RawSet(lua.LString("Username"), lua.LString(a.Username))
    tab.RawSet(lua.LString("Password"), lua.LString(a.Password))
    tab.RawSet(lua.LString("Protocol"), lua.LString(a.Protocol))
    return tab
}

// I borrow it from https://github.com/yuin/gopher-lua?tab=readme-ov-file#sharing-lua-byte-code-between-lstates
// ============================
// ============================
// CompileLua reads the passed lua file from disk and compiles it.
func CompileLua(filePath string) (*lua.FunctionProto, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(file)
    chunk, err := parse.Parse(reader, filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    proto, err := lua.Compile(chunk, filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return proto, nil
}
// ============================
// ============================


func DoCompiledProto(L *lua.LState, proto *lua.FunctionProto, a *Action) error {
    lFunc := L.NewFunctionFromProto(proto)
    L.Push(lFunc)

    tab := a.ToLuaTable()
    L.Push(tab)
    return L.PCall(1, lua.MultRet, nil)
}

var luaProtos sync.Map

func Worker(ctx context.Context) {
    var a *Action

    Actions = make(chan *Action)

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            break
        case a = <-Actions:
            func() {
                L := lua.NewState()

                defer L.Close()

                // Run FunctionProto if it cached
                if proto, ok := luaProtos.Load(a.ScriptPath); ok {
                    if err := DoCompiledProto(L, proto.(*lua.FunctionProto), a); err != nil {
                        log.Print(err)
                        return
                    }

                } else {
                    // Compile and cache FunctionProto if cache miss
                    if newProto, err := CompileLua(a.ScriptPath); err != nil {
                        log.Print(err)
                        return
                    } else {
                        luaProtos.Store(a.ScriptPath, newProto)

                        // Run FunctionProto
                        if err := DoCompiledProto(L, newProto, a); err != nil {
                            log.Print(err)
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            }()
        }
    }
}
```

And the bruteforce.lua:

```lua
-- first index of args contains the "action" table
local args = {...}
local action = args[1]

print("IP="       .. (action.ClientIP and action.ClientIP        or "nil"))
print("Port="     .. (action.ClientPort and action.ClientPort    or "nil"))
print("Net="      .. (action.ClientNet and action.ClientNet      or "nil"))
print("Username=" .. (action.Username and action.Username        or "nil"))
print("Password=" .. (action.Password and action.Password        or "nil"))
print("Protocol=" .. (action.Protocol and action.Protocol        or "nil"))

if action.Repeating == true then
    print("Action is repeating")
end
```

If there is a better way, please let me know. ;-)